# NSArray with double entries

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray

I have a NSArray with a lot of entries. But some of them are twice.
And i want that every entry is only once in the Array.

Have somebody an idea how i can do this?

This is how i've tried it:

```
NSSet *newsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:news];
newsOrte = [newsSet allObject];
```

Comment: Please let me know whats the error in my answer and code... I posted first almost 1 hour ago, next answer came after 5 minutes, I got downvoted without any comment.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya : I also got downvote, but I added code first, before your code

Comment: @Prateek : I gave the idea as this idea was suffiecient to solve. I got vote up , Later I posted the code. and after the code i got downvoted. And I know my code is working fine, without any error.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya You still get one upvote, I am on -2 loss for this question though my code has worked

Comment: @Prateek : dont worry boy, you are not winning employee of the stackOverflow award :D  Come here learn and let stackoverflow earn money :p

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `NSSet` effectively the object being stored must conform to the `NSObject` protocol and implement the `hash` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash)) and `isEqual:` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a)) methods.

Please ensure your object implements these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
NSArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"A",@"C",@"A", nil];    
NSMutableArray *arr=[NSMutableArray new];
for(id obj in array){
    if (![arr containsObject:obj]) {
        [arr addObject:obj];
    }
}
array=arr;
NSLog(@"==> %@",array);
```

Also you can do in this way:

```
NSArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"A",@"C",@"A", nil];    
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:array forKeys:array];
array=[dict allKeys];

NSLog(@"==> %@",array);
```

Output :

```
==> (
    A,
    B,
    C
)
```

Comment: Is this different from your other (deleted) answer?  Still looks over complicated.

Comment: @trojanfoe : second way is still same, first one is newly added.

Answer (score -1):

Here is code

```
NSArray* originalArray = ... // However you fetch it
NSMutableSet* existingNames = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray* filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id object in originalArray) {
   if (![existingNames containsObject:[object name]]) {
      [existingNames addObject:[object name]];
      [filteredArray addObject:object];
   }
}
originalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:filteredArray];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: However you fetch it? what do you mean?

Comment: pass your original array there

Comment: ok, but in the last line there is a error. he don't know filteredArray

Comment: Thank you a lot :)  But there is another mistake in the loop: Local declaration of 'originalArray' hides instance variable

Comment: remove NSArray* before originalArray declaration

Comment: check your array, NSLog it

Comment: @user1823117 : I can say this answer is correct with minor error, you can solve it easily. But you did downvote on him and mine...please tell me why bro?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I guess he dont have privileges to downvote as it requires 125 atleast

Comment: As I said to AnoopVaidya, I would imagine you were downvoted (and not by me, BTW) as this also isn't a good solution.  That's a lot of work in order to convert an `NSArray` into an `NSSet` when `[NSSet setWithArray:]` does it all for you anyway.  This avoids the OP's issue rather than addressing it.

Comment: @trojanfoe : I am using same code and its working, so I don't agree with you